# Project Referencing Assembly of the Same Name

Tags: c#

I have project SandBox and SandBoxLibrary (SandBoxLibrary used to be SandBox, just copied on the disk, renamed the folder and opened). I have added some library functions into SandBoxLibrary, build it, copied dlls into SandBox. Now in SandBox I have referenced the SandBoxLibrary DLL, called the public method from there (intellisense works OK), but when I run this project, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XT.X' from assembly 'SandBoxBinary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Both projects have the same assembly name. If I change one, it works ok. Now the question is I would expect compiler to issue warning/error on this and I would not expect a runtime unhandled exception... Could someone shed some light into the following issue? What are the rules?

Thanks.

Comment: And what/which project is the SandboxBinary from the error message related to?

Comment: That's the question, they are both named the same...

Comment: The compiler cannot know this will go wrong, and it doesn't *have* to go wrong, the mishap takes place very late in the build.  When MSBuild copies the dependent assemblies into the build directory.  One overwrites the other.  It doesn't have to go wrong when one of them is in the GAC.

Comment: Oh well, you are right, I completely forgot that compiler copies all the non-GAC references into output directory and they are named the same so I guess its overwritten. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments by Hans Passant, the problem is the that both assemblies share the same name (i.e. the filename) and the library is not in GAC. When the the code is compiled suddenly there need to be two DLL files with the same name in the output directory (i.e. big\Debug) - the main assembly and the library, both named the same. That is what was causing the problem.

Quite obvious when you put all the pieces together.